# Angular URL formatting issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have:

```
var mappedContacts = "C:/filestore/_images/contacts";
```

And:

```
   <div data-ng-controller="SelectUserController" id="account-group-widget" data-ng-init="initContacts(mappedContacts )">
```

I pass in mappedContacts in the initiContacts method (using asp.net) but in the backend I get the formatted URL:

```
<div data-ng-controller="SelectUserController" id="account-group-widget" data-ng-init="initContacts(mappedContacts )">
```

However I get :

C:filestore_imagescontacts instead of C:/filestore/_images/contacts

Is there any Angular UI directive to stop the removal of the slashes ?

Comment: what does your `initContacts` do?

Comment: It just returns the string I entered in the view. Basically the URL which is being auto formatted.

Comment: put `console.log(initContacts)` inside `initContacts`, what's the output?

Comment: Please provide us with the code for your `initContacts` method `:)`.

Comment: $scope.initContacts = function (data) {
                    console.log("data ::::::::::::::::::::::::", data );
                    return data;
                }; It returns C:filestore_imagescontacts

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use:

```
$scope.mappedContacts = "C:/filestore/_images/contacts";
```

Comment: Are you serious ? This is not a hardcoded value. It needs to be passed through the front end and picked up in the controller and is getting formatted.